# Gulp не компилирует шаблон Panini

Tags: javascript, gulp, шаблонизаторы

В проекте используется gulp. В gulpfile.js настроен автоматический релоад с помощью browsersync.

Пытаюсь подключить и настроить шаблонизатор [panini](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html) в файле gulpfile.js так:

```
gulp.task('compile-html', function() {
gulp.src('html/pages/**/*.html')
    .pipe(panini({
        root: 'html/pages/',
        layouts: 'html/layouts/',
        partials: 'html/partials/',
        helpers: 'html/helpers/',
        data: 'html/data/'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
    .on('finish', browserSync.reload);
 });


gulp.task('compile-html:reset', function(done) {
panini.refresh();
done();
});
```

Вот весь [код](https://jsfiddle.net/rn741qos/)

При вызове `watch` страница `index.html` не компилируется. В чем м.б. ошибка?

Comment: Может быть лишний символ `;` в строке `data: 'html;/data/'`

Comment: это опечатка, но причина не в ней. обновила вопрос

Comment: Возможно, проблема в путях. Следует перепроверить. Также, возможно, связано вот с чем: `"Note that Panini loads layouts, partials, helpers, and data files once on first run. Whenever these files change, call panini.refresh() to get it up to date."` - попробуй вызывать рефреш на `gulp.watch`

Comment: спасибо, ошибка была в не правильном пути